# I am trying to initialize a matrix, but get the same row repeated

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to initialize a matrix of a list of lists of characters.

```
aRow = [ '0', '0','0' ]
aGrid = [ aRow, aRow, aRow ]
```

After it appeared like one row repeated three times, I tried modifying the rows as follows and printing the result:

```
aGrid[1][0] = '1'
aGrid[2][0] = '2'

print( aGrid )
```

It looks like I am getting the third row three times.

```
[['2', '0', '0'], ['2', '0', '0'], ['2', '0', '0']]
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

In python, when you assign values you're really assigning references to the values. So this statement creates a list with the value `['0', '0', '0']` and assigns a reference to that value to `aRow`:

```
aRow = [ '0', '0','0' ]
```

And so this statement then creates a list with three references to the same list:

```
aGrid = [ aRow, aRow, aRow ]
```

In Python, lists are mutable values, so changes to the underlying value are reflected by all references to that value. So:

```
aGrid[1][0] = '1'
```

and:

```
aGrid[2][0] = '2'
```

Both change the first element of the underlying list that all three references in `aGrid` are referencing, and so the last change is the one you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are. You need to copy the object if you want the contents to be different.

```
aGrid = [aRow, aRow[:], aRow[:]]
```

Comment: A little terse, but you answer does provide the solution and not just explain why it does not work.  (Unfortunately, that was my question.  Next time i will just ask "how do you fix this?")